# Source .pdbrc on mac to add tab completion to python debugger with anaconda

Tags: python, macos, configuration, anaconda, rc

I have put a file in my $HOME folder called .pdbrc that has the following code inside of it:

```
import rlcompleter
pdb.Pdb.complete = rlcompleter.Completer(locals()).complete
```

However, when I run the python debugger with a program, it does not "source" the .pdbrc file and the tab completion does not work. Typing in the home folder

```
source .pdbrc
```

obviously does not work either since the .pdbrc rile is in python. How do I get these python debugger settings to apply to my python debugger? I am on mac and using anaconda

Thanks in advance!